# Error while installing Microsoft visual studio Professional 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I am trying to install Microsoft visual studio Professional 2010 on my Windows XP SP3 edition. I am getting the error "vs_setup.msi could not be open" :

[image: Screenshot]

I have seen some forums mentioning the same problem for different reasons, and mostly because of having a previous version of Microsoft visual studio installed, but this is the first time for me to install it. **Any idea how to fix that ?**

Note: The actual setup files are in the path "G:\Visual Studio 2010 Professional". I do not know why the setup is trying to look for vs_setup.msi inside the "G:" directly ! Of course it is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this setup is from DVD image and it's hardcoded to work in root directory.
Try to move all setup files to G:\ or another drive root

Comment: OMG, I was working on a legacy app and trying to use Virtual PC w/XP mode to install VS2005!!  It would NOT install no matter what I did....til I found this!! Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't like the spaces in the installation folder name. Rename "Visual Studio 2010 Professional" to VS2010Pro and see if it doesn't start working.

Also look for the setup log in %temp%. Sometimes it's cryptic but you can usually get SOME idea of what went wrong. Maybe edit your question with the errors from that log. It's called dd_*something**something* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package.

With 7zip open and extract VSIsoShell.exe in a New Directory (there are many files inside of this .exe).
After this is done, redirect to the right path w/ the extracted files  (with vs_setup.msi file).

7zip is an Open source Windows utility for manipulating archives (www.7-zip.org)